# Width isn't reading in mui table

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

This is my reactjs mui table. For a start, I want to be able to edit the TableCell in Indicators.
I only need to edit it's width.

```
<Box>
            <TableContainer component={Paper} flex="6" >
              <Table size="small" aria-label="a dense table" sx={{ width: '100%'}}>
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell rowSpan={2} sx={{ width: '30%' }}>
                      Indicators
                    </TableCell>
                    {['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th'].map(qtr => (
                      <React.Fragment key={qtr}>
                        <TableCell colSpan={4}>{qtr} Quarter</TableCell>
                      </React.Fragment>
                    ))}
                    <TableCell rowSpan={"2"}>Total</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                  <TableRow>
                    {[1, 2, 3, 4].map(qtr => (
                      <React.Fragment key={qtr}>
                        <TableCell>count</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>base</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>%</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>Remarks</TableCell>
                      </React.Fragment>
                    ))}

                  </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                

              </Table>
            </TableContainer>
          </Box>
```

I tried px, % and rem but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try styled-components which you can override the css for that component, add !important so it force to override the current width

```html
import styled from 'styled-components'
// import Table
const TableStyled = styled(Table)`
   width: 100% !important;
`
export {TableStyled}
```

then you can import and replace it for Table component

```html
<Box>
            <TableStyled component={Paper} flex="6" >
             // rest of the code
            </TableStyled>
          </Box>
```